# Marshalling 16 bit unsinged int in Qt DBUS

Tags: qt, types, marshalling, dbus

In QT we have following representations of 16 bit unsigned available:

```
typedef unsigned short int  uint16_t;   (in stdint.h)
typedef unsigned short      quint16;    (in qglobal.h)
```

What is the difference between the these two? I got an external header file (which I must not modify) with a following typedef:

```
typedef uint16_t MyCustomId;
```

This "MyCustomId" field is used in a slot-signal to communicate with DBUS.

```
class CMyDbusProxy: public QDBusAbstractInterface
{
Q_OBJECT
Q_SIGNALS: 
    void Test(MyCustomId);
};
```

The problem is that the signal sent from the DBUS service isn't noticed in CMyDbusProxy, so no slot at all will be fired. If I change manually the typedef to (which I shouldn't do, it's just for testing):

```
typedef quint16 MyCustomId;
```

everything works fine. The signal on the DBUS service side has "signature='q'", which means uint16.

How to overcome this type-matching problem and have the signal received with "uint16_t"?